# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.dc.pr.Rasterizer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

For two of my Android projects I get during build progress following error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.dc.pr.Rasterizer

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Furtheron with --stacktrace I get following log output:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.dc.pr.Rasterizer
    at sun.dc.DuctusRenderingEngine.getRasterizer(DuctusRenderingEngine.java:365)
    at sun.dc.DuctusRenderingEngine.getAATileGenerator(DuctusRenderingEngine.java:397)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.AAShapePipe.renderPath(AAShapePipe.java:152)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.AAShapePipe.fill(AAShapePipe.java:68)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.fill(PixelToParallelogramConverter.java:164)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.fill(ValidatePipe.java:160)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.fill(SunGraphics2D.java:2527)
    at com.android.ide.common.vectordrawable.VdPath.draw(VdPath.java:561)
    at com.android.ide.common.vectordrawable.VdGroup.draw(VdGroup.java:108)
    at com.android.ide.common.vectordrawable.VdGroup.draw(VdGroup.java:108)
    at com.android.ide.common.vectordrawable.VdTree.drawTree(VdTree.java:78)
    at com.android.ide.common.vectordrawable.VdTree.drawIntoImage(VdTree.java:102)
    at com.android.ide.common.vectordrawable.VdPreview.getPreviewFromVectorTree(VdPreview.java:349)
    at com.android.ide.common.vectordrawable.VdPreview.getPreviewFromVectorXml(VdPreview.java:285)
    at com.android.builder.png.VectorDrawableRenderer.generateFile(VectorDrawableRenderer.java:152)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.lambda$addItem$1(MergedResourceWriter.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
```

When I remove all my vector drawables and replace them with any other *.png images it works and the error is gone. **What is the issue with the vectors?** It was working previously, why is it nomore working?

EDIT:
Project top level build.gradle is [here](https://pastebin.com/FCFdfnEM)
Module level build.gradle is [here](https://pastebin.com/RTryYp8k)

Comment: post your build.gradle for your app

Comment: @wick.ed Done, see OP

Comment: hmm. This says if you use latest AS it should work. `https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37057730`. Good luck!